# Images randomly positioned on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

I am trying to get lots of .gifs to appear in random positions on the page. I have managed to get the first one to execute this action but for some reason all the ones that come after remain static despite having the same id. The .gifs also have a draggable function.

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cherry+Swash:400,700">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title></title>

  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    html {
      font: 16px"Segoe UI", "Segoe WPC", Helvetica, Arial, "Arial Unicode MS", Sans-Serif;
    }
  }
  #w {}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="w">
    <center>

      <img src="images/.gif" height="150" class="draggable ui-draggable" alt="paper" id="image">
      <img src="images/.gif" height="150" class="draggable ui-draggable" alt="paper" id="image">
      <img src="images/.gif" height="150" class="draggable ui-draggable" alt="paper" id="image">
  </div>
  <script>
    window.onLoad = Prep();

    function Prep() {
      window_Height = window.innerHeight;
      window_Width = window.innerWidth;

      image_Element = document.getElementById("image");
      image_Height = image_Element.clientHeight;
      image_Width = image_Element.clientWidth;

      availSpace_V = window_Height - image_Height;
      availSpace_H = window_Width - image_Width;

      var changeInterval = 3000; // Time has to be in miliseconds. So, 3000 is 3 seconds
      setInterval(moveImage, changeInterval);
    }

    function moveImage() {
      var randNum_V = Math.round(Math.random() * availSpace_V);
      var randNum_H = Math.round(Math.random() * availSpace_H);

      image_Element.style.top = randNum_V + "px";
      image_Element.style.left = randNum_H + "px";
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.draggable').draggable({
        scroll: true,
        cursor: "move"
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.draggable').draggable({
        scroll: true,
        cursor: "move"
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `id` tags once. Use classes instead, for example:

```
<img src="images/.gif" height="150" class="draggable ui-draggable image" alt="paper">
```

and

```
image_Element = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
```

You'll need to make other changes as well but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: thanks very much for the tip. None of the .gifs move whatsoever now though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using JQuery, you could do something like..

```
window.onload = Prep();
var window_Height, window_Width;
var changeInterval = 3000;

function Prep(){
  window_Height = $(window).height();
  window_Width = $(window).width();
}

function moveImage(imgEl,space_V,space_H){
  var randNum_V = Math.round(Math.random() * space_V);
  var randNum_H = Math.round(Math.random() * space_H);

  imgEl.style.top = randNum_V + "px";
  imgEl.style.left = randNum_H + "px";
}

$('img').each(function(){
  var img = $(this);
  var image_Height = img.height();
  var image_Width = img.width();
  var availSpace_V = window_Height - image_Height;
  var availSpace_H = window_Width - image_Width;

  setInterval(moveImage(img,availSpace_V,availspace_H),changeInterval);
});
```

I've shortened your *Prep* function to just get the window dimensions and changed your *moveImage* function to have the necessary variables passed as arguments. This way, you can use the function for each image individually.

The JQuery *.each* targets each *img* element on the page and executes the *moveImage* function accordingly. If you want get more specific rather than targeting all image elements, you could just select the ones in the div with id **w** by doing something like..

```
$('#w').find('img').each(function(){...
```

Hope this helps!